# How to insert raw html strings in Binding.scala

Tags: binding.scala

Reposting this question from [gitter](https://gitter.im/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/archives/2018/03/06).

Suggestions were made to modify simply the innerHTML attribute but I thinkt this is quite unconvenient.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful if you could post the code here too, so we can see what the issue is? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Reposting this answer from [gitter](https://gitter.im/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala?at=5812a792806316005dc9fad3).

```
<div innerHTML={renderToString(latex)}></div>
```

Comment: I paste the original posts here, hoping it will help other people who face to the same problem.